# Not able to Install

Tags: software-installation

I am not able to install any software (from software center) in ubuntu, after installing it gets failed and when i checked i detail, below error is coming .. please help me out for installing it,

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: JAVA_HOME: command not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
Error in function: 
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: JAVA_HOME: command not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

I have following output for /etc/environment, java_home is already installed there.

output of `cat /etc/environment`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/u‌​sr/local/games" 
JAVA_HOME =/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin
```

I have updated the language support and getting the below error

```
amulbhatia@Nadar:~$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-en
[sudo] password for amulbhatia: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  language-pack-en-base
The following packages will be upgraded:
  language-pack-en language-pack-en-base
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 321 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/459 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,421 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: JAVA_HOME: command not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks in advance friends,

Comment: output of cat /etc/environment     PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME =/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin

Comment: Can you elaborate When did this start happening, what was the last thing you did beforethis started, what program are you trying to install, is this a clean install ?

Comment: @markkirby - today, software and update installation for new packages and application was happened, i downloaded whatever was available, and tried to install, during installation, same error came, i ignored that one, and installation got failed, then i tried to install one application from ubuntu software center and again it got failed, i have no idea else, what has happened to my  ubuntu.. is it possible to revert back to my old versions of packages..

Comment: Have you updated language support ? LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1" These errors seem related to that

Comment: You can find it be searching for language in the dash pleases do this a post back

Comment: Can you confirm there's a space between `JAVA_HOME` and  `=/usr/...`? And that the PATH and JAVA_HOME are on different lines?\

Comment: @markkirby - have tried and getting the same error, ( output is updated in question ), Thanks for your time , Please help

Comment: Do what it says run sudo apt-get auto remove

Comment: @muru - Oh my God, Because of only space, this much problem, thanks it solved my problem - i did - 1. removed the space and made them in single line (without space), This solved my problem, thanks for your time, i have one more problem i will update in other question, thanks muru, mark and other for their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of how `/etc/environment` is applied by PAM, but it looks like it is sourced. So when it encounters a line like:

```
JAVA_HOME =/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin
```

the shell will interpret `JAVA_HOME` as a command because of the space before `=`, which is a grave error since `JAVA_HOME` is not found in the PATH nor defined as an alias or function. An error in a `source` causes the shell to exit (since maintenance scripts are run that way), which is why this error stopped installations. (Equivalently, a space after `=` causes the shell to see `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin` as a command, which is not that bad, but still a problem.) So the correct line is:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem for many months. I didn't give attention at first but it started troubling when I would download updates and they won't install. Finally, I found the solution. The problem was the path of `JAVA_HOME`. My path was:

```
JAVA_HOME = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle'
```

I replaced it with

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
```

So, basically I removed the quotes and the spaces.

How to do it ?

Check the `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` path variables by using

```
$ cat /etc/environment
```

It shows something like

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle'
```

I suggest you to take a back up of the original environment variable in `.orig` using

```
sudo cp /etc/environment /etc/environment.orig
```

use `sudo nano command` to forcefully change the variable path

```
sudo nano -w /etc/environment
```

After editing the path by removing quotes and spaces use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit, press <kbd>Y</kbd> to confirm and rename the new file.

and check the path again.

```
 $ cat /etc/environment
```

Now update and upgrade your system for smooth performance and installations.